# Make all website's folders inaccessible

Tags: language-agnostic

I have a webpage online. When I type an address the browser will look for the index.html of that folder. If it doesn't **it'll just list it's contents. I don't want the browser to show the contents**, I want it to, for example, just show a blank page.

Some of these folders store files that are referenced as downloads on other pages of my website, so the *some* contents of the folder need to be downloadable, though I don't want them to be visible. So to download a specific file the user must know the entire path. If they are listed, he/she is immediately aware of all files I have there and therefore can download them.

The way I worked this around was to put a blank index.html on each of the folders I want to have this behavior. But this is a pretty dumb solution. Is there a way to like change the permissions of the folder so that it's contents cannot be listed but still be downloadable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disable directory browsing using .htaccess:

- Open your .htaccess file
- If a `Options Indexes` line exists, change it to `Options -Indexes`. Otherwise add `Options -Indexes` as a new line.

Found in [http://www.techiecorner.com/](http://www.techiecorner.com/106/how-to-disable-directory-browsing-using-htaccess-apache-web-server/)

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what web server you're using, IIS, Apache, etc.  You need to turn off directory browsing.

Enable or Disable Directory Browsing in IIS 7
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109%28WS.10%29.aspx

How to disable directory browsing , APACHE
http://www.felipecruz.com/blog_disable-directory-listing-browsing-apache.php

If you can't edit the configuration directly, then the easiest thing to do is put an `index.html` file in the directory that is blank or redirects somewhere else.

Comment: And how do I discover that? I think it's Apache. I use 000webhost's hosting.

Comment: @DiAlex, as their tech support if they provide a way to configure this.  If not, add an `index.html` file to the directory.